# How to use Databound and AutoBind together for Kendo Combobox

Tags: javascript, combobox, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I want to use DataBound and AutoBind both together in Kendo Combobox.
But Not able to use it.
My DataBound is used to Insert the First Item into the list and If I use AutoBind='false' then I am not able to set it.

```
    $("#Number").kendoComboBox({
        dataTextField: "NUM",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        filter: "startwith",
        autoBind: false,
        suggest:true,
        minLength: 5,
        dataBound: function () {
               var dataSource = this.dataSource;
               var data = dataSource.data();
               if (!this._adding) {
                   this._adding = true;
                   if (IS_ANALYST == 'Y') {
                       dataSource.insert(0, {
                           "NUM": "Create New Analysis",
                           "ID": -1
                       });
                       this.select(function (dataItem) {
                           return dataItem.NUM === "Create New Analysis";
                       });
                   }
                   else {
                       dataSource.insert(0, {
                           "NUM": "Select",
                           "ID": -2
                       });
                       this.select(function (dataItem) {
                           return dataItem.NUM === "Select";
                       });
                   }
                   this._adding = false;
               }
           },
});
```

So How to resolve this.
I want to use AutoBind='false' and also need to insert the first item as shown
Any alternative for this?
Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try in Open event like

```
<script>
function combobox_open(e) {
  // handle the event
}

var combobox = $("#Number").data("kendoComboBox");
combobox.bind("open", combobox_open);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I solved it by using different approach..I have posted the answer..

Answer (score 0):

We can use Request End in Datasource:

```
 requestEnd: function (e) {
                      if (IS_ANALYST == 'Y') {
                            e.response.unshift({ ID: -1, NUM: 'Create New Analysis' });
                           }
                      else {
                           e.response.unshift({ ID: -2, NUM: 'Select' });
                           }
                     },
```